# Text overlapping with custom button in TextView swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uitextview

**Problem**: Im trying to build a "comment" component to my app. I have managed to create a textview that expands as more text gets typed, and also created a button within the textview that will stay top right corner at all times. However when i write text, the text will go under the button and is not visible. What i want is that the text does not overlap the button, and instead just stays away from the button.

**Question**
How can i achieve this ?

[image]

This is my code:

```
class ClickedOnPostViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    var answersOf: Answer?


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentText: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        commentText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [

            commentText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            commentText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            commentText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            commentText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 43)
            ].forEach{ $0.isActive = true }


        commentText.addSubview(button)

        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentText.topAnchor).isActive = true
        button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bringSubview(toFront: button)


        commentText.delegate = self
        commentText.isScrollEnabled = false


        //Keyboard listeners

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)

        //  qNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)





        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = .orange
        button.setTitle("Click Me", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()



    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }



    @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
    }


    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            commentText.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: .infinity)
        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)

        textView.constraints.forEach { (constraints) in
            if constraints.firstAttribute == .height {

                constraints.constant = estimatedSize.height

            }
        }

    }

}
```

***UPDATE*** issues with Sh_Khan current answer:

**Before typing the last character that will overlap button**

[image]

**After typing the last character that will overlap button**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
commentText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(commentText)
view.addSubview(button)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    commentText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    commentText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor), 
    commentText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 43),
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentText.topAnchor),
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentText.trailingAnchor,constant:20)
])

commentText.delegate = self
commentText.isScrollEnabled = false
```

> Don't mix RTL with LTR logic in your case using rightAnchor with trailingAnchor
>
> If the UI of comment textfield is build in storyboard / xib , don't set constraints for it again

---

to have the width of textView  = 80% , remove this

```
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
```

and add this

```
commentText.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier:0.8,constant:-20),
```

Comment: Hi again Sh_Khan. The textfield is created in my storyboard, i dont really get what you mean with dont set constraints for it again - as the textview gets bigger if user types alot of words (so i need to have adjustable constraints). I tried implementing your code, but i still have the same issue.

Comment: Now the text wont overlap the button, we are making progress. However this is what happens when i type the last character before it will overlap with the button (see the edit with pictures added to my question). Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: The text just disappears and does not increase textview size like it used to do

Comment: Currently you set a fixed height , it can be implemented be it needs some complex calculations to re-change the height better you can use this https://github.com/muukii/NextGrowingTextView

Comment: Okay can i ask you one more thing. If this is the case, a fix would be to split the textview and the button programmatically. How do i split it so the textview will cover for example 80 % of the width ,  and the button will cover 20%, and when the textview expands, the button will follow the top at the same top as the textview?